# How to delete all except a directory in Makefile?

Tags: bash, shell, makefile, sh

The following command set is working on linux prompt.

```
%cd ${ADIR}/exe; shopt -s extglob; rm -rf !(BDIR)
```

But it is not working in Makefile

Linux command - works

```
%cd ${ADIR}/exe; shopt -s extglob; rm -rf !(BDIR)
```

Command in Makefile

```
        @cd ${ADIR}/exe; shopt -s extglob; rm -rf !\(BDIR\)
```

Make file message

```
rm: cannot remove `!(BDIR)': No such file or directory
```

Comment: Your Makefile command contains extra backslashes. Why?

Comment: /bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `cd ./adir/exe; shopt -s extglob; rm -r !(BDIR)'
make: *** [clean] Error 2

Comment: error without "\"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there's a weird behavior of bash in that the shopt setting won't take effect until the newline, so any globbing on the same line won't recognize it.  Try this at your shell prompt:

```
$ shopt -s extglob; echo !(BDIR)
bash: !: event not found
```

Then try it in two lines:

```
$ shopt -s extglob
$ echo !(BDIR)
  ...works
```

Unfortunately this means it's almost impossible to use this with make.

You should use the POSIX-compatible version suggested in triplee's comment and avoid the need for special shells altogether.

Oh, it seems the answer was deleted.  Anyway, do something like this instead:

```
foo:
        cd ${ADIR}/exe && for f in *; do \
            case $$f in (BDIR) : ok ;; (*) rm -rf "$$f" ;; esac; \
        done
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your Makefile is that it escapes `(` and `)`, which makes the shell interpret them literally.

The second issue,

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

is caused by `make` using `sh` to execute commands, not `bash`.

The `!(...)` wildcard syntax (and `extglob`) are only supported by bash, not sh.

You could call `bash` explicitly:

```
        @bash -c 'cd ${ADIR}/exe; shopt -s extglob; rm -rf !(BDIR)'
```

But that doesn't work either, because `extglob` doesn't take effect until the next line of input has been read, so `!( )` still throws a syntax error.

We need a way to run a multi-line command using a single invocation of the shell. Unfortunately `make` makes this unnecessarily complicated.

One possible solution:

```
SHELL = /bin/bash

...
        @bash -c $$'cd ${ADIR}/exe; shopt -s extglob\nrm -rf !(BDIR)'
```

This tells `make` to use `bash` to execute all recipes (not `/bin/sh`). We then run `bash` again manually, but using `$'...'` to quote the command string. This lets us write `\n` to embed a literal newline, which makes `extglob` / `!( ... )` work.

We need double `$$` to escape the `$` for `make`, so `$'...'` becomes `$$'...'`.

I'm not very happy with this solution.

Comment: Or, of course, the obvious reimplementation in pure portable  `sh`; `for d in ./*/.; do case $d in ./BDIR/.) continue;; esac; rm -rf "$d"; done`

Comment: Thanks for help, but not working. I work in bash envirionment. host$ echo $0
bash

Comment: I tried both, @bash -c 'cd ...' and SHELL = /bin/bash, but the same error message